# How to call a method from one component to another reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to reuse methods/functions from a component to another component, how can i do that?
I have 2 files and 2 components function a() b() and c() has been declared in a component functionA, I want use the same functions in functionB which is in seperate file, how to make a call for it?

**file1.js**

```
const functionA = props =>{
    const a = () =>{
    };
    const b = () =>{
    };
    const c = () =>{
    };
    return(
    //...
    )
    }
```

**file2.js**

```
const functionB = props =>{
    
    return(
    //...
    )
    }
```

Comment: Move the functions into their own files and import them into each component?

Comment: this is no react specific question. Just import the function " import { funcA, funcB} from 'myfunctions.js'.
In myfunctions.js: export function funcA(){} etc..